# A generalisation of Tchebychev inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities

Let $f,g \in C(\mathbb R)$ with $\exists M \in \mathbb R^*, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2, M\times (f(x)-f(y))(g(x)-g(y)) \geq 0$.

> Is it true that exists $ u$ any real function, and $a,b$ monotone function with $f(x)=a(u(x))$ and $g(x)=b(u(x))$ ?

No answer here : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h3261085

About the inequality : https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In%C3%A9galit%C3%A9_de_Tchebychev_pour_les_sommes

Comment: Tchebytchev doesn't exist. French translitteration is Tchebychev ("ch" pronounced in the French way), and English one is Chebyshev.

Comment: The French transliteration is Tchebycheff, I think.

Comment: I don't see an inequality.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Tchebycheff exists, but see the title of the Wikipedia page https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnouti_Tchebychev . In French textbooks I've mainly (if not only) seen "Tchebychev".

Comment: @YCor : I guess you are right. However, today is the first time when I see "Tchebychef" or"Tchebychev". I have seen "Tchebycheff" a number of times, as e.g. [here](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s1-42.1.757). The correct Russian pronunciation is Chebyshof (with the Russian "o" stressed), I think. So, the initial French transcription, with "f"or "ff" at the end, was more accurate than the current one.

Comment: @IosifPinelis regarding the last consonant, the final -ov, -ev from Russian are very common (Gorbatchev, Prokofiev, etc) and systemically pronounced "-off" or "-eff". The story about the final vowel is another issue.

Comment: @YCor : Yes, as a native Russian speaker, I know about "-off" and "-yeff" (rather than "-eff" :-) ). As for the final vowel sound, my analysis course professor G. P. Akilov (a co-author of his [Functional Analysis book with Kantorovich](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780080230368/functional-analysis) told us that the right pronunciation is with the stressed Russian "o". This is in part confirmed by the spelling "Chebyshov" on that [French Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnouti_Tchebychev).

Comment: Previous comment continued: The full Russian spelling is probably "Чебышёв" (pronounced as "Чебышов"), which was probably reduced in typing to "Чебышев". Similarly, the full Russian spelling of 
"Горбачев" (Gorbachev) is "Горбачёв", pronounced as "Горбачов" (Gorbachoff), again with the stressed Russian "o" sound in the final syllable.

Comment: @IosifPinelis the noble family name Чебышев is older than the letter ё, so, it never was Чебышёв reduced to Чебышев

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Interesting. I did not know that [the letter "Ё" was created by (...) Karamzin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo_(Cyrillic)) only in 1797. However, clearly Karamzin created this letter to represent the existing sound in the language. So, for the reasons stated in my previous comments, I still tend to believe that "Чебышев" should be pronounced as "Чебышов". Do you disagree with this?

Comment: @IosifPinelis this is accurate: pronounce as Чебышёв, write as Чебышев

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\les\lesssim\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The answer is yes.

Indeed, without loss of generality, we have the co-monotonicity condition
$$(f(x)-f(y))(g(x)-g(y))\ge0 \tag{$-10$}\label{-10}.$$
(Otherwise, replace $g$ by $-g$.)

For real $x$ and $y$, write
$y\les x$ if $f(y)\le f(x)$ and $g(y)\le g(x)$. For real $x$, let
$$E_x:=\{y\in\R\colon y\les x\}.$$
The relation $\les$ is transitive, so that for all real $x$ and $y$ we have
$$y\les x\implies E_y\subseteq E_x.$$

For real $x$, let now
$$u(x):=\mu(E_x),$$
where $\mu$ is any finite measure whose support set is the entire real line $\R$.

It is enough to show that for all real $x$ and $y$ we have
$$u(y)\le u(x)\implies f(y)\le f(x)\ \&\ g(y)\le g(x); \tag{0}\label{0}$$
see details on this at the end of this answer.

Suppose the contrary. Then without loss of generality for some real $x$ and $y$ we have
$$u(y)\le u(x)\ \&\ f(y)>f(x) \tag{10}\label{10}$$
and hence, by the co-monotonicity \eqref{-10} of $f$ and $g$ we have $g(y)\ge g(x)$, so that $x\les y$ and hence
$$E_x\le E_y. \tag{20}\label{20}$$

Moreover, by \eqref{10} and the continuity of $f$, there is some some $c$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f(y)>f(c)>f(x)$ and hence $f(y)>f(z)>f(x)$ for all $z$ in some neighborhood $N_c$ of $c$. So, again by the co-monotonicity \eqref{-10} of $f$ and $g$ we have $g(y)\ge g(z)\ge g(x)$ for $z\in N_c$, so that $N_c\subseteq E_y\setminus E_x$.

So, in view of \eqref{20},
$$u(x)=\mu(E_x)\le\mu(E_y)-\mu(N_c)=u(y)-\mu(N_c)<u(y),$$
which contradicts \eqref{10}. $\quad\Box$

---

**Details on \eqref{0}:** Take any $t\in u(\R)$, so that $t=u(x)$ for some real $x$, and let
$$a(t):=f(x). \tag{30}\label{30}$$
This yields a well-defined function $a\colon u(\R)\to\R$, because, in view of \eqref{0}, if $u(y)=u(x)$ for some real $x$ and $y$, then $f(y)=f(x)$. Moreover, we have $f(x)=a(u(x))$ for all real $x$.
Furthermore, for any $s$ and $t$ in $u(\R)$ such that $s<t$ we have some real $x$ and $y$ such that $u(x)=s<t=u(y)$, so that, in view of \eqref{30} and \eqref{0}, $a(s)=f(x)\le f(y)=a(t)$. So, the function $a$ on $u(\R)$ is nondecreasing. If desired, the function $a$ can be extended from $u(\R)$ to $\R$ by the formula
$$\tilde a(t):=\sup\{a(s)\colon s\in u(\R)\cap(-\infty,t]\}$$
for all real $t$, so that $\tilde a(t)=a(t)$ for $t\in u(\R)$. Re-denoting $\tilde a$ as $a$, we will have a nondecreasing function $a\colon\R\to\R$ such that $f(x)=a(u(x))$ for all real $x$.

Similarly, we will have a nondecreasing function $b\colon\R\to\R$ such that $g(x)=b(u(x))$ for all real $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slightly more elementary proof; note that continuity of $f$ and $g$ are in fact not required.

Without loss of generality (replace $g$ by $-g$ if necessary) we can assume that $f$ and $g$ are such that
$$ (f(x) - f(y))(g(x) - g(y)) \geq 0, \quad \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}. \tag{A}\label{A}$$

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the set
$$ U:= \{(f(x), g(x)) : x\in \mathbb{R} \}$$
then expression \eqref{A} is equivalently written as
$$ (s_1, t_1), (s_2,t_2)\in U \implies (s_1 - s_2)(t_1 - t_2) \geq 0. \tag{B}\label{B}$$
Geometrically this means that the vector $(s_1 - s_2, t_1 - t_2)$ must live in the first or third quadrants, or their closure. So the mental image of $U$ should be a set that travels diagonally up $\mathbb{R}^2$ always in a direction between North and East. This suggests the following lemma.

> **Lemma 1** The function $\phi:U\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(s,t) = s+t$ is injective.

*Proof*: Suppose not, then there exists $(s_1,t_1) \neq (s_2,t_2)$ such that $s_1 + t_1 = s_2 + t_2$, which implies $s_1 - s_2 = t_2 - t_1$. Since the two pairs are not equal, neither difference is zero, and this would force $(s_1 - s_2)(t_1 - t_2) < 0$, contradicting \eqref{B}. Q.E.D.

Since $\phi$ is injective, there exists $\psi:\phi(U) \to U$ such that $\phi\circ \psi$ is the identity. I claim the following:

> The desired result can be obtained by letting $u(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and $a, b$ be the first and second components of $\psi$.

Our argument above already shows that $a,b$ are well-defined, and that $a(u(x)) = f(x)$ and $b(u(x)) = g(x)$. It suffices to show that they are monotone. This is established by the following lemma.

> **Lemma 2** If $\phi(s,t) < \phi(s',t')$, then $s \leq s'$ and $t \leq t'$.

*Proof*: Assume for contradiction and WLOG that $s > s'$, then as we hypothesized $s+ t < s' + t'$ we must also have $t < t'$. But then $(s-s')(t-t') < 0$, contradicting (B). Q.E.D.

---

What we gain if $f$ and $g$ are assumed continuous is that $u$ is now a continuous function, and hence its image is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. One can show then the set $U$ is in fact a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: This is very nice. However, the proof of the monotonicity can be simplified, as follows. We have to to show that $f(x)+g(x)<f(y)+g(y)$ implies $f(x)\le f(y)$. But otherwise we would have $f(x)>f(y)$ and hence $g(x)<g(y)$, which would contradict the co-monotonicity.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I have now shamelessly stolen it.

Answer (score 0):

Choose an arbitrary $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $h(x) = (f(x) - f(x_0))(g(x) - g(x_0))$. The continuity of $f$ and $g$ implies the continuity of $h$. Additionally, the condition   $$(f(x) - f(y))(g(x) - g(y)) > 0$$  means that $f$ and $g$ must exhibit the same monotonic behavior (either both increasing or both decreasing) over any interval where they are monotonic. Moreover, $h(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq x_0$, showing that neither $f$ nor $g$ can be constant over any interval.

Define $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$u(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x} \sqrt{|h(t)|} \, dt$$ Since $h$ is continuous, so is $|h|$ and $u$ is continuous. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $u'(x) = \sqrt{|h(x)|} $ for $x \ne x_0$. Since $h(x) > 0$ for  $x \ne x_0$, we have $u'(x) > 0$ for $x \neq x_0$. To ensure $u$ is strictly increasing across its entire domain, we note that the continuity of $u$ and the positivity of $u'$ for all $x \neq x_0$ directly guarantees that $u$ must be strictly increasing over all of $\mathbb{R}$.

To ensure $u$ is invertible, a sufficient condition is that $u(x)$  becomes unbounded as $x$  approaches either positive or negative  infinity, along with the requirement that $ u$ covers the entire range of $\mathbb{R}$. These conditions guarantee that for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists at least one $x$ such that $u(x) = c$. Since $h(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq x_0$,  a sufficient condition for the unboundedness of $u(x)$ is that the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)$ or $\lim_{x \to -\infty} h(x)$ exists and is non-zero.

Because $u$ is continuous and strictly increasing, the Inverse Function Theorem guarantees that its inverse function $u^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ exists and is also continuous and strictly increasing. Additionally, since $u'(x) \neq 0 $ for $x \neq x_0$,  the Inverse Function Theorem ensures that $u^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable on its domain. Let $a, b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $a(y) = f(u^{-1}(y))$ and $b(y) = g(u^{-1}(y))$.  The continuity of $a$ and $b$ follows directly from the continuity of $f$, $g$, and $u^{-1}$. Furthermore, where $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, their compositions with the continuously differentiable $u^{-1}$ ensure that $a$ and $b$ are also differentiable.

To show that $a$ and $b$ inherit the monotonic properties of $f$ and $g$, consider any $y_1 < y_2$. Since $u$ is strictly increasing, $u^{-1}(y_1) < u^{-1}(y_2)$. Because $h(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq x_0$, it's guaranteed that $f$ and $g$ (and consequently $a$ and $b$) maintain the same monotonic behavior relative to their values at $x_0$.  Thus, $a$ and $b$  will also be strictly monotone if $f$ and $g$ are strictly monotone.

Finally, note that $$u(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^{x_0}\sqrt{|h(t)|}dt = 0$$ Therefore, $a(u(x_0)) = f(u^{-1}(u(x_0))) = f(x_0)$, and similarly, $b(u(x_0)) = g(x_0))$. Since $a$, $b$, $f$, and $g$  all exhibit the same monotonic behavior relative to $x_0$, the desired representations $f(x) = a(u(x))$ and $g(x) = b(u(x))$ hold for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Maybe this can be extended to other domains besides real numbers. Or even to higher dimensions.

Comment: But $(f(x) - f(y)) (g(x) - g(y)) $ can be nul, for value $x\neq y$

Comment: @Dattier: that should be clarified in the question. When I read a statement that $f$ has constant sign I interpret it (same as the answerer here) as either $f > 0$ always or $f < 0$ always.